# MySQLi doesn't retrieve mediumtext field

Tags: php, mysqli

doing some db work I've encountered the following problem: PHP MySQLi extension seem to have a problem retrieveing a `mediumtext` field.
I've tested that with this code:

```
$q = 'SELECT p.*, c.slug, c.descr FROM projects p INNER JOIN categories c ON p.cat = c.id WHERE p.pid=1';
$res = $db->query($q);
$info = $res->fetch_assoc();
var_dump($info);
```

Every other field is retrieved successfully and running that same query using PMA also works.
I'm confused as to what could be the cause,
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you paste some example of your problem? I've used mediumtext before and I've never get any issue.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa What kind of examples do you want me to provide?

Comment: For example what do you expect and what do you get.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa I expect some text in hebrew (another field in that query is also in hebrew and is retrieved successfully so I don't believe it's the problem -- the encoding is UTF-8), and all I get is NULL value.

Comment: You have to post more info. What's your table structure? Which is the field that is mediumtext? What data do you have? Unless you post this noone can help you.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa [table structure](http://i.imgur.com/MtvVH.png) (as displayed in PMA). Field is `descr, already specified the data I have.

Comment: I believe it was meant to be `p.descr` instead of `c.descr`